# Spring PUT-Request, best way to do it

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

So i know that in REST, generally when i do a PUT-request i should specify the resource i want to update in the URL like this for example: `.../collections/{collectionId}`

Implementing that in spring boot for my Role resource would look like this:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/roles")
public class RoleController {

  private RoleRepository roleRepository;

  @Autowired
  public RoleController(RoleRepository roleRepository) {
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
  }

  @PutMapping("/{roleId}")
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Role> putRole(@PathVariable long roleId, @RequestBody Role newRole) {
    Optional<Role> roleOptional = this.roleRepository.findById(roleId);
    if(roleOptional.isPresent()) {
      Role roleToBeSaved = roleOptional.get();
      roleToBeSaved.name = newRole.name;
      roleToBeSaved.description = newRole.description;
      // set more attribute
      this.roleRepository.save(roleToBeSaved);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(roleToBeSaved);
    }
    throw new RoleNotFoundException('could not find role with id + ' + roleId);
  }
}
```

But isn´t that way more work than needed, because the newRole inside the RequestBody already contains the id, so i could just do instead:

```
@PutMapping("/{roleId}")
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Role> putRole(@PathVariable long roleId, @RequestBody Role newRole) {
    this.roleRepository.save(newRole);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(newRole);
  }
```

This results in an unused PathVariable, but i do not need it cause newRole already contains the ID. So what is the optimal way to do a PUT-Request like this?

Edit: I could obviously just change the URL to something like `.../roles/role` without having a PathVariable and just sending the newRole inside the RequestBody. But that is not how a PUT-Request URL generally should look like, right?

Comment: Is the `roleId` an integral part of the role?  Or just used because you put it in a database/map and use that as the key?

Comment: Your first method properly handles the case when a non-existing role is found, the latter does not and allows for new roles being added through an update method. Not sure if that is what you really want. Also that code should really be in a service class and not int he controller, and for mapping you might want to a framework like `MapStruct`. Could you do the second one, yes, should you probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/rest-api-path-vs-request-body-parameters) post.
A Restful Api should be self explaining and is not about saving every byte possible.
Restful Api follows the princip of declaring what you want to do.
In your example you want to update the role. A role contains of an id and a role name. A path variable describes the unique path to the resource and the requestbody represents the new updated resource. A body only with the property role does not discribe the role resource because the id is missing. This reduces complexity by enhancing redundancy. But for a good rest-api always try to keep it as simple and self declaring as possible.

In short, point to your resourcer with the path and send the whole definition of your resource in the body including the id you've already used in the path.

Comment: The link is no longer valid. Does your answer summarize the linked content?